# Check if a plot exists on an already open MATLAB subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, subplot

I have a subplot in MATLAB that has already been created, its axes colors set, etc, and all ready. I then plot a histogram on it.

Now I come back to it, (within a loop), and I want to check is there is something already 'plotted' on that subplot, histogram or normal plot. If there was something there, do_something, otherwise, do_something_else.

How to I check the 'occupancy' of a subplot or plot in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether or not the `subplot` has `children`:

```
isempty(get(yourSubplotHandle, 'children'))
```

This statement is `true` for empty subplots.

Comment: Wouldnt the colors I previously get on teh subplot be children too? I can check this, but why arent they considered children?

Comment: I would guess that for all the formatting you set different properties of the axes instead of creating children.